# Fancybox won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
<a id = "single_image" href = "images/decoration/bottom4.jpg"><img src="images/decoration/bottom4.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a#single_image").fancybox();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get fancybox to display an image but it just keeps linking to the image externally. This is the very shortened version of my code but it still won't work properly as is. Typically, this issue is caused by loading jQuery twice, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Depending on the fancybox version, jQuery 1.4 might not be up-to-date enough. You will also want to remove the white space in your attribute declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the instructions given here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

</head>

<body>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/decoration/bottom4.jpg"><img src="images/decoration/bottom4.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```